# Searching always returns empty list in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to implement filtering in a page that contains some data, the page shows three different entities: `Branches`, `Items` and `Categories`, so I used a view model:

```
   public class WarehouseData
    {
        public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
    }
```

in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sort, string search)
        {
            var warhouse = new WarehouseData();
            warhouse.Items = db.Items.Include(c => c.Categories).ToList();
            warhouse.Branches = db.Branches;
            ViewBag.Search = search;

            warhouse.Branches = db.Branches.ToList();
            switch (sort)
            {
                case "q_asc":
                    warhouse.Items = warhouse.Items.OrderBy(c => c.Quantity).ToList();
                    ViewBag.Sort = "q_desc";
                    break;
                case "q_desc":
                    warhouse.Items = warhouse.Items.OrderByDescending(c => c.Quantity).ToList();
                    ViewBag.Sort = "q_asc";
                    break;
                default:
                    warhouse.Items = warhouse.Items.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList();
                    ViewBag.Sort = "q_asc";
                    break;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                warhouse.Items = warhouse.Items.Where(i => i.Name.Contains(search)).ToList();
                ViewBag.Search = search;
            }
            return View(warhouse);
        }
```

this is the `Index` view:

```
@model WarehouseManagementMVC.ViewModels.WarehouseData

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2 style="display:inline-block">Registered Branches | </h2> @Html.ActionLink("Add New Branch", "Create", controllerName: "Branch")
@foreach (var branch in Model.Branches)
{
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(branch.Location, "Details", "Branch", routeValues: new { id = branch.Id }, htmlAttributes: null)</li>
    </ul>
}
<hr />
<h2>All Items Available</h2>
<div>
    @using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Warehouse", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <input type="text" name="search" value="@ViewBag.Search"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    }
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>@Html.ActionLink("Quantity", "Index", new { sort = ViewBag.Sort, search = ViewBag.Search })</th>
        <th>Categories</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>

                @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Details", "Item", routeValues: new { id = item.Id }, htmlAttributes: null)


            </td>
            <td>
                <span>@item.Quantity</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                @{foreach (var cat in item.Categories)
                    {
                        @cat.Name <br />
                    }
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

But when I search, the result is always empty list, why?

Comment: This code is pretty confusing, and you seem to be setting and re-setting properties multiple times.  When you step through in a debugger, where specifically does the problem first manifest?  Which list is unexpectedly empty, and where are you attempting to populate that list?  What happens in the debugger when you try to populate that list?

Comment: I did another debugging now, and found that it's case sensitive, for instance, I have "Nokia" items, if I searched "nok" the list returned is empty, and if I searched for "Nok" the list will return Nokia items. It's strange because I did it before without encountering this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only two things that would cause `Items` to be empty here:

1. There's no items in the DB.
2. None of those items have `Name` values that contain the search term. Be advised in particular here that `Contains` is case-sensitive. So if the name is `Foo` and you searched for `foo` *it will not match*. If you want to do case-insensitive search, then you should cast both `Name` and `search` to either lowercase or uppercase before comparing:

   ```
   Where(m => m.Name.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()))
   ```

While we're here. A search should ideally filter at the database level. Currently, you're selecting all items in the database and then filtering them in-memory, which is highly-inefficient. As soon as you you call `ToList()` in the second line of the action, the query has been sent, but you have to do so in order to set `warhouse.Items`. Instead, you should store your items in a temporary variable, i.e. `IQueryable items = db.Items.Include(c => c.Categories);` and do all your conditional ordering and filtering on that. Then, finally, set `warhouse.Items = items.ToList();`.

Comment: I didn't know about the `Contains` case sensitiveness until I did another debugging

Comment: FWIW, it's not so much that it's case-sensitive as rather that it operates on lists. A string is essentially a list of char. So what you're doing in essence is asking if one list of char contains another list of char. When you think about it this way, it's obvious why "Foo" != "foo", because "F" is very literally a different char from "f".

Answer (score 0):

I found that the search is case sensitive, this solved it:

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
        warhouse.Items = warhouse.Items.Where(i => i.Name.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())).ToList();
        ViewBag.Search = search;
    }
```

If you have another suggestion for the code , I appreciate sharing it.